# Словообразование и словоизменение

Tags: словообразование

Как доходчиво объяснить детям, в чем разница между однокоренными словами и формами одного и того же слова? Объяснение:"У однокоренных слов разное лексическое значение, а у форм слова одно и то же", по-моему, детей только запутывает, ведь им только что сказали, что однокоренные слова -- это слова с общим лексическим значением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если меняется только окончание, то это формы одного и того же слова. Если поменялось что-то ещё, то это уже разные слова, пусть и однокоренные.

Answer (score 1):

**Словообразование.** Общее лексическое значение слова складывается из значений отдельный морфем. Однокоренные слова имеют одинаковый корень, но приставки и суффиксы у них разные, поэтому и лексическое значение разное: лес, лесной, лесник.

**Словоизменение.** Разные формы одного слова - это словоформы данного слова с различными окончаниями: лесник - лесника - леснику. В этом случае набор морфем одинаковый (одно и то же  лексическое значение), а разными являются окончания.